# canvas image disappears

Tags: javascript, html, html5-canvas

I have this function to load image on canvas:

```
function myImage() {
  var canvas=document.getElementById("myCanvas");
  var ctx=canvas.getContext("2d");
  var img=document.getElementById("image");
  ctx.drawImage(img,0,0);
}
```

Image loads fine, and there are other images on canvas, but with this image, when I use any control to move or resize the other images, this one disappears.

to load image I use:

```
<img id="image"  src="1.png" width="64" height="64" onclick="myImage(this)">
```

Well I updated the function:

```
function myImage() {
  var canvas=document.getElementById("myCanvas");
  var ctx=canvas.getContext("2d");
  var img=document.getElementsByClassName("test");
  ctx.drawImage(img,0,0);
}
```

and the images

```
<img class="test" src="1.png" width="64" height="64" onclick="myImage(this)">
<img class="test" src="2.png" width="64" height="64" onclick="myImage(this)">
<img class="test" src="3.png" width="64" height="64" onclick="myImage(this)">
```

but I get this error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Type error 
myImage
onclick
```

in the last line of the function

Comment: all the images have same "image" id?

Comment: no, other images have different id and are called by another functions

Comment: dont know what your entire code is doing but I think each id should be unique per element, is there any reason to have them all with same id?

Comment: there are various groups of images, each group has his own id, to select and load one image of each group and work with them.

Comment: well, I think your problem is related to the way you select more than an image with same id. could you maybe try to use document.getElementsByTagName('img'); or related. I mean, I never want to have more than an element with same id

Comment: There are a lot of images, how can be built this function to call images one by one and load the one selected?

Answer (score 1):

Maybe better to use:

```
document.getElementsByClassName('test');
```

and have the images you want with a particular shared class